# Taking one record from group by without manually typing all columns

Tags: sql, hiveql, presto

I have the a table with the following column:

```
id, col_1, col_2, col_3, .... col_1000, timestamp
```

I want to have just one record for each id, taking the latest timestamp. That is, my query would be:

```
select id, max_by(col_1, timestamp), max_by(col_2, timestamp), max_by(col_3, timestamp), ... max_by(col_1000, timestamp), max_by(timestamp, timestamp) group by id
```

Since there are so many columns, I am wondering is there a way I could do something like:

```
select max_by(*, timestamp) group by id
```

So that I don't have to manually type all columns? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use [`row_number()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#row_number):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also express this using a correlated subquery or `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id, max(timestamp) as max_timestamp
      from t
      group by id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id and t.timestamp = tt.max_timestamp
```